# webのログイン後の状態を保持する技術について

Tags: python, python3, session

Pythonのrequests.ssessを使用して、webサイトへのログイン後、セッションIDなどを保持した状態で操作を続けたいと考えているのですが、このセッションID自体はwebのログイン状態を保持する技術として標準のものなのでしょうか？

このセッションIDはcookieに保持されると考えているのですが、cookie以外にも保持される場所はあるのでしょうか？

webサイトによってはrequests.sessionではログイン状態を保持できないサイトもあると思う　例：セッションIDとは別の機能でログイン状態を保持する（ページ移動のたびにログインしなければならないサイトはさすがにないと考える。）のですがその場合はどのような技術で保持しているなど分析はchromeの検証を使用してどのように見ていけば良いのでしょうか？

具体的には [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.jp/) をpythonのrequestsでログインしてセッション状態を保持したいと考えています。

Comment: 聞きたいことが複数あるように見えるので、質問を分けたほうがよろしいかもしれません。

Comment: cookieはクライアントサイドで保持する仕組みですが、サーバサイドでセッションを管理する方法もあります。

Comment: 添削、返信ありがとうございます。つまりサーバサイドの場合、requests.sessionを使用してのセッション保持は難しいということでしょうか？